# Using placeholders or environment variables in sudoers

Tags: cron, sudo

Is it possible to use in `sudoers` rules any kind of placeholders (not just wildcards) or environment variables?

What I would like to do is to verify that user (the one `sudo`ing a command) passes as an argument to the command his own user name. To be more precise I want to write some `sudoers` rules for `crontab` that enforce that the `crontab` is provided with `-u` argument and user name.

I mean something like that:

```
Cmnd_Alias CRONTAB_LIST = /usr/bin/crontab -u $USER -l
```

From my experiments it seems that `$USER` doesn't work. It is treated explicitely and to match that user has to enter

```
sudo crontab -u \$USER -l
```

In [`sudoers` man](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html) I have noticed placerholders like `%{user}`. But it seems they are used only with the `Default` for parameter `iolog_dir`.

So is there any way around that problem (that doesn't involve "hardcoding" user name)?

---

I noticed similar question: [Is is possilbe to use environment variables in sudoers rules?](http://Is%20is%20possilbe%20to%20use%20environment%20variables%20in%20sudoers%20rules?). But it seems to me that it is focused on environmental variables while I don't really need them. I just want to match to user name. (Which could be done differently.

Comment: Then write a simple wrapper script that does what you need instead and give `sudo` rights to that rather then to the crontab command directly.

Comment: That surly would do. But I hoped for some solution without introducing any new scripts/programs.

Comment: On the second time reading your question you want the `$USER` argument to be the username of the user running sudo, right? - Why? Users can already maintain their own contabs without super user privileges by simply calling the `crontab` command without a username argument...

Comment: To be precise I want to "access" (in `sudoers` rules) user name of the user calling `sudo`. The particular use case is to enforce proper argument `-u` to `crontab`.

On our system `crontab` doesn't have SUID bit set and access to it is controlled by `sudo`. But that requires some tricks so that after `sudo`ing `crontab` still uses proper user rather than `root`.

Among the tricks is use of `stay_setuid` in `sudoers`. But I wanted to explore other options as well. Among them is an option of allowing user to run `sudo crontab` only with `-u` for himself.